# Fatal error wheen running update.php

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

Kindly assist me in solving this error. It appears once I try to run update.php

> Fatal error: Class CToolsCssCache contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

This is how my css-cache.inc file looks like;

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Custom cache implementation for the CTools CSS cache.
 */

class CToolsCssCache implements DrupalCacheInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */

  public function clear($cid = NULL, $wildcard = FALSE) {
    // Only clear the caches if the wildcard is set, this ensures that the cache
    // is only cleared when the full caches are cleared manually (eg by invoking
    // drupal_flush_all_caches()), and not on a cron run.
    // @see drupal_flush_all_caches()
    // @see system_cron()
    if ($wildcard) {
      ctools_include('css');
      ctools_css_flush_caches();
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function get($cid) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getMultiple(&$cids) {
    return array();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function isEmpty() {
    return FALSE;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function set($cid, $data, $expire = CACHE_PERMANENT) {
  }

}
```

I think it is affecting the site such that any updates done cannot display on the live site. I will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

there are a few steps you need to do:

1. Please upgrade you  [Drupal Core](https://www.drupal.org/upgrade)
2. Apply this patch: [Patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/ctools-cache-handler.patch) to your Ctools Module, you can be found the file here **/includes/css-cache.inc**

Comment: Thanks DartkteK, I tried the patch a few days ago but it dint work.what could i be doing wrong?Thank you

Comment: Can you tell us how you could fix it?

Comment: the patch had a few (+) signs and i was leaving one there so i kept on getting different  errors but after i removed all the(+) signs the issue was solved. i copied the patch as is and followed the -10,6 +10,12 rules.thank you for your time DarkteK.

Comment: Ohh, yeah, you need to remove those signs, the (+) means the new lines you need to add to your file, remember mark the answer as solved ✔✔ :) take care  !